# How can I access the number of the dataProvider's current data set?

Tags: php, phpunit

In PHPUnit, for a test decorated with a `@dataProvider`, is there a way to find out the index of the dataset (within the array provided by the dataProvider) being currently used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method 1 - Format Array

You have to format your dataProvider method to supply the array index `($key)` as well as the `$value`:

```
<?php

class DataProviderTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testMethod($key, $value)
    {
        if ($key === 1) {
            $this->assertEquals('two', $value, 'pass');
        }

        if ($key === 2) {
            $this->assertEquals('two', $value, 'fail');
        }
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        $data = array('one', 'two', 'three');

        $holder = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $holder[] = array($key, $value);
        }

        return $holder;
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I formatted the provider to supply the key and value in two method arguments..

### Method 2 - Call private property

Since your comment I have done some more digging and I have found the method that PHPUnit are using internally to get the dataProvider array index on failure, the index is stored in a private property of the test case class (`PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`) called `dataName`.

I am mainly a Magento developer and we use the [EcomDev_PHPUnit module](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/) to help with testing, it comes with a nice reflection helper to access restricted properties since Magento is not built for testing and has a lot of them, see: https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/blob/master/lib/EcomDev/Utils/Reflection.php

I can not find a public accessors for this property so you will have to use reflection, maybe you can open a pull request?

```
<?php

class DataProviderTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function test($value)
    {
        $key = EcomDev_Utils_Reflection::getRestrictedPropertyValue($this, 'dataName');

        if ($value === 'zero') {
            $this->assertEquals($key, '0', 'pass');
        }

        if ($value === 'two') {
            $this->assertEquals($key, '1', 'fail');
        }
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        return array(
            array('zero'),
            array('one'),
            array('two')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now. I don't really like it, though, as it seems redundant and inefficient (adding an extra loop just for array keys). I was hoping for PHPUnit to somehow expose the dataset number, given that it also prints it when the test fails with a specific dataset.

Comment: @BernhardReiter added another method that uses phpunit internals.

Comment: For future Googlers:

In a more recent version of PHPUnit (not sure since when), there is a public method `dataDescription()` in `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` which returns the value of the private `dataName` property.

Although this can only be used if you are using strings for your keys, so doesn't answer the original question if you're just looking for the numerical key.

Comment: @antriver According to the latest PHPDoc, `dataDescription()` was added in 5.4.0.

Comment: In PHPUnit 9 the method to get the index/name of the dataset has changed from `dataDescription` to `dataName`.

Comment: PHPUnit 8.5.17:  
`dataName()` => exmple: 12  
`getDataSetAsString()` => example: testUpdateAction with data set #12

Answer (score 1):

There is also ...

```
    /**
     * Gets the data set description of a TestCase.
     *
     * @param bool $includeData
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDataSetAsString($includeData = true)
```

This will return something like (for example)

```
string(51) " with data set "Empty set with no columns from set""
```

or

```
string(87) " with data set "Empty set with no columns from set" (array(), array(), 0, '\n\n\n\n\n')"
```

Comment: Your answer makes no sense.

Comment: This one worked for me. I just had to call `$this->getDataSetAsString();` on my testing method.

Comment: ini PHPUnit 9.5 u can access it using `$this->dataName()` so u can only get "Empty set with no columns from set" ;-)